# Using Python variables for table name and column value in an SQL query

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a Python function to read from an SQL table into a pandas DataFrame:

```
def project_cable_collector(dbase, table, project):
    engine = create_engine(dbase)
    df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * from table WHERE project_id = project', engine)
    return (df)
```

However it returns `sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError`:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "table"
LINE 1: SELECT * from table WHERE project_id = project
```

I tried editing quotation marks to see if that's a fix, but it fails.
Any ideas?

Comment: I think that the topic of using placeholder or creating queries with variables should be part of any SQLAlchemy tutorial, just keep reading. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

An exact fix to your current problem might be to use an f-string:

```py
def project_cable_collector(dbase, table, project):
    engine = create_engine(dbase)
    sql = f"SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE project_id = {project}"
    df = pd.read_sql(sql, engine)
    return (df)
```

*However*, note that it is highly undesirable to build a SQL query string this way using concatenation and substitution.  The reason is that your function invites something called SQL *injection*, which means that someone could pass in a malicious SQL code fragment into the function and try to get your Python script to execute it.  Instead, you should read about using prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I'll look into prepared statements!

Answer (score 0):

Further to Tim's answer, you'll need to use an f-string to insert the table *name* into the SQL text, but you should use a parameter to specify the column *value*:

```py
from sqlalchemy import text

# …

def project_cable_collector(dbase, table, project):
    engine = create_engine(dbase)
    sql = f"SELECT * FROM {table} WHERE project_id = :project_id"
    df = pd.read_sql_query(text(sql), engine, params=dict(project_id=project))
    return df
```

Note also that `read_sql_query()` is preferable to `read_sql()`.